# Firebase presence system in iOS application

Tags: ios, firebase

I have integrated Firebase into my iOS apps I want to integrate user presence system, is there any Firebase API that tracks which user is online & offline?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a way

You may use firebase's `.info/connected`

This is updated every time Firebase's Realtime Database client connection state changes.

```
let connectedRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: ".info/connected")
connectedRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
  if snapshot.value as? Bool ?? false {
    print("Connected")
  } else {
    print("Not connected")
  }
})
```

[Read more here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities)

Comment: Thanks for answer!!...
But where to pass userid suppose I want to see status if some user i.e. userid1, userid2 etc... then where to pass?

Comment: Check out this documentation:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence